# How to stop button from disappearing off the screen?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I've ran into a problem while trying to create a basic form. After clicking the Add another file?, there's a replicate box that appears which is intended, but the Submit Order button gets pushed out of the screen and I can't seem to get it back. Is there a way to solve this? I'm working on Google apps script and here is the code:

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML')     
}
```

HTML.html

```
<body>
<style type="text/css"> 
* {
    margin: 0
}
.container {
    width: 1250px
}
.header {
    display: block;
    background-color: #8000FF;
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%;
    border:3px solid #41087B;
    padding: 10px;
}
.header img {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.header h1 {
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align:center
}
.label {
   float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    color: red;
}
.label-container {
    width: 570px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto

}
.label p {

    padding: 2px;
}
.inputBox {
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
.inputBox p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px
}
.label2 {

    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    color: red
}
.label2 p {
    padding:2px
}
.inputBox2 {
    float:left;
}
.inputBox2 p {
    padding: 1px
}
.contentBackground {
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    clear:left;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px
         display: block;
}
.uploadFile p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color:red
}
.content p {
    text-align: center;
    color:red;
    padding: 7px
}
.dropDown p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    height:
}
.moreFiles {
    text-align:center
}
.textBox {
    text-align: center
}
.textBox p {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px
}
input.uploadButton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 170px;
    left: 582px

}
</style>



  <div class="container">

  <form id="myForm">

    <div class="header">


      <h1>Order Form</h1>

    </div>

   <div class="label-container">

    <div class="label">          
      <br>
      <p><b>Customer Name</b></p>
      <p><b>Due Date</b></p>
      <p><b>Phone #</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox">
      <br>
      <p><input type="text" name="myName"></p>
      <p><input type="text"></p>
      <p><input type="text"></p><br>
    </div>

    <div class="label2">
      <br>
      <p><b>Contact</b></p>
      <p><b>E-mail</b></p>
      <p><b>PO#</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputBox2">
      <br>
      <p><input type="text"></p>
      <p><input type="text"></p>
      <p><input type="text"></p><br>
    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="contentBackground">

     <div class="uploadWrapper">

        <div class="fileUpload">

            <div class="uploadFile">
                <p>Upload File: <span style="color:black"><input type="file" name="myFile" /></span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Width(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Height(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Quantity <input type="text" style="width: 100px"></p>
            </div>

        </div>

     </div>

     <div class="dropDown">
        <p>Material <select style="max-width: 10%;">
                <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
                <option value="Vinyl Banner">Vinyl Banner</option>
                <option value="Adhesive Vinyl">Adhesive Vinyl</option>
                <option value="Polygloss">Polygloss</option>
                <option value="Translucent Vinyl">Translucent Vinyl</option>
                <option value="Static Cling Clear">Static Cling Clear</option>
                <option value="Static Cling White">Static Cling White</option>
                <option value="Reverse Static Cling">Reverse Static Cling</option>
                <option value="Outdoor Paper">Outdoor Paper</option>
                <option value="Backlit Film">Backlit Film</option>
                <option value="Foam">Foam</option>
                <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
                <option value="Sintra">Sintra</option>
                <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
                <option value="Fabric">Fabric</option>
                <option value="All Cling">All Cling</option>
            </select>
            Lamination <select>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Matte">Matte</option>
                <option value="Gloss">Gloss</option>
                <option value="Lexan">Lexan</option>
                <option value="Erasable">Erasable</option>
            </select>
            Mounting <select>
                <option value="3/16&quot Foam">3/16" Foam</option>
                <option value="3/16&quot Gator">3/16" Gator</option>
                <option value="1/8&quot Sintra">1/8" Sintra</option>
                <option value="24point Card">24point Card</option>
                <option value="50point Card">50point Card</option>
                <option value="Adhesive Back">Adhesive Back</option>
                <option value="MDF">MDF</option>
                <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                <option value="Masonite">Masonite</option>
                <option value="020 Styrene">020 Styrene</option>
                <option value="040 Styrene">040 Styrene</option>
                <option value="060 Styrene">060 Styrene</option>
                <option value="080 Styrene">080 Styrene</option>
                <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
            </select>
            Ink <select>
                <option value="Indoor">Indoor</option>
                <option value="Outdoor">Outdoor</option>
            </select></p>
     </div>

   </div>

   <div class="moreFiles">
     <a href="#" id="add">Add another file?</a>
   </div>

   <div class="textBox">
     <p><label>Remark?</label></p>
     <textarea></textarea>
   </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Order" class="uploadButton"
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">

  </form>
  </div>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#add").on("click", function () {
var $last = $(".contentBackground").last();
$last.clone().insertAfter($last);
});
```

This is what it looks like [image]

and this is what it looks like after clicking Add another file?[image]

As you can see the Submit Order button disappears and I cannot scroll down further. Is there a way to fix this?

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hLzkpoxt/

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow-y: auto; to the container. This will allow it to auto size height of the container so it dont cut off your text/button when your list get longer. Also gotta fix that absolute positioning on the button.

```
 <body>

  * {
        margin: 0
    }
    .container {
        width: 1250px
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .header {
        display: block;
        background-color: #8000FF;
        margin:auto;
        width: 50%;
        border:3px solid #41087B;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .header img {
        float:left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .header h1 {
        color: white;
        line-height: 80px;
        text-align:center
    }
    .label {
       float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        color: red;
    }
    .label-container {
        width: 570px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        margin: auto

    }
    .label p {

        padding: 2px;
    }
    .inputBox {
        float:left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .inputBox p {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px
    }
    .label2 {

        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        color: red
    }
    .label2 p {
        padding:2px
    }
    .inputBox2 {
        float:left;
    }
    .inputBox2 p {
        padding: 1px
    }
    .contentBackground {
        background-color:#D8D8D8;
        clear:left;
        width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 200px
             display: block;
    }
    .uploadFile p {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        color:red
    }
    .content p {
        text-align: center;
        color:red;
        padding: 7px
    }
    .dropDown p {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 40px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        height:
    }
    .moreFiles {
        text-align:center
    }
    .textBox {
        text-align: center
    }
    .textBox p {
        text-align:center;
        padding: 5px
    }
    .button {
        text-align: center
    }
    input.uploadButton {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;

}




      <div class="container">

      <form id="myForm">

        <div class="header">


          <h1>Order Form</h1>

        </div>

       <div class="label-container">

        <div class="label">          
          <br>
          <p><b>Customer Name</b></p>
          <p><b>Due Date</b></p>
          <p><b>Phone #</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="inputBox">
          <br>
          <p><input type="text" name="myName"></p>
          <p><input type="text"></p>
          <p><input type="text"></p><br>
        </div>

        <div class="label2">
          <br>
          <p><b>Contact</b></p>
          <p><b>E-mail</b></p>
          <p><b>PO#</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="inputBox2">
          <br>
          <p><input type="text"></p>
          <p><input type="text"></p>
          <p><input type="text"></p><br>
        </div>

       </div>

       <div class="contentBackground">

         <div class="uploadWrapper">

            <div class="fileUpload">

                <div class="uploadFile">
                    <p>Upload File: <span style="color:black"><input type="file" name="myFile" /></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <p>Width(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Height(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Quantity <input type="text" style="width: 100px"></p>
                </div>

            </div>

         </div>

         <div class="dropDown">
            <p>Material <select style="max-width: 10%;">
                    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
                    <option value="Vinyl Banner">Vinyl Banner</option>
                    <option value="Adhesive Vinyl">Adhesive Vinyl</option>
                    <option value="Polygloss">Polygloss</option>
                    <option value="Translucent Vinyl">Translucent Vinyl</option>
                    <option value="Static Cling Clear">Static Cling Clear</option>
                    <option value="Static Cling White">Static Cling White</option>
                    <option value="Reverse Static Cling">Reverse Static Cling</option>
                    <option value="Outdoor Paper">Outdoor Paper</option>
                    <option value="Backlit Film">Backlit Film</option>
                    <option value="Foam">Foam</option>
                    <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                    <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
                    <option value="Sintra">Sintra</option>
                    <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
                    <option value="Fabric">Fabric</option>
                    <option value="All Cling">All Cling</option>
                </select>
                Lamination <select>
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="Matte">Matte</option>
                    <option value="Gloss">Gloss</option>
                    <option value="Lexan">Lexan</option>
                    <option value="Erasable">Erasable</option>
                </select>
                Mounting <select>
                    <option value="3/16&quot Foam">3/16" Foam</option>
                    <option value="3/16&quot Gator">3/16" Gator</option>
                    <option value="1/8&quot Sintra">1/8" Sintra</option>
                    <option value="24point Card">24point Card</option>
                    <option value="50point Card">50point Card</option>
                    <option value="Adhesive Back">Adhesive Back</option>
                    <option value="MDF">MDF</option>
                    <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                    <option value="Masonite">Masonite</option>
                    <option value="020 Styrene">020 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="040 Styrene">040 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="060 Styrene">060 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="080 Styrene">080 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
                </select>
                Ink <select>
                    <option value="Indoor">Indoor</option>
                    <option value="Outdoor">Outdoor</option>
                </select></p>
         </div>

       </div>

       <div class="moreFiles">
         <a href="#" id="add">Add another file?</a>
       </div>

       <div class="textBox">
         <p><label>Remark?</label></p>
         <textarea></textarea>
       </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit Order" class="uploadButton"
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">

      </form>
      </div>





<div id="output"></div>

</body>





 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        var $last = $(".contentBackground").last();
        $last.clone().insertAfter($last);
    });
    </script>

    <script>
        function fileUploaded(status) {
            document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
        }
    </script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hLzkpoxt/3/)